# Assets upload and Update Asset Indexes issues

Tags: assets, upload

There seem to be some issues with asset uploading, and i can't figure out what the problem is. Here's a summary:

- After uploading an asset it doesn't show up in the Assets listing
- If i do a 'Update Assets Indexes' it says this about files 'The following files could not be found. Should they be deleted from the index?'
- If i run 'Update Assets Indexes' again, a couple (but not all) of the uploaded files appear in the Assets listing?

The assets file path seems to be in order. The log files says:

'[error] [application] Could not delete the file' ... 'because the file does not exist.'

Pointing to a file in 'craft/storage/runtime/assets/sources/'

I tried loads of stuff already, including uploading all craft files again in a new folder, but no dice.. Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks, Bob

Comment: Not certain but sounds like an issue with permissions, try checking step2 from the installation guide.
http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing

Comment: @j00lz Thanks, i tried that (even set it too 777) but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in your browser's console when you do any of this stuff?

Comment: @BradBell No javascript errors it seems, just this message: Double-instantiating a select on an element garnish-0.1.js:223, but i guess that is not related.

Comment: And on a side note, it only seems to happen after you delete a file and try to upload that same file again.. after which the log says it could not delete a file in 'craft/storage/runtime/assets/thumbs/...' because it doesn't exist

Comment: And a final note, the images do get uploaded but they just don't show in the Assets listing.

Comment: I have the same issue. How do I get this image out of the system? Everything works except for that one photo.